# Media Library and paragraphs not working

Tags: media, ajax, paragraphs

I have a paragraph with multiple fields, one of them is a media field (document type).

If I add a new paragraph and then add media I got "ajax error".

If I add new paragraph and save content type, then edit same content type and add media it works as expected.

My conclusion is drupal or paragraphs are not handling the right way with multiple ajax request.

Setps to reproduce the error:

1 - Create a paragraph with some fields (lets say the paragraph name is "file info":

- name (text field)
- date (date only, required, default value "-None-")
- document (field media)

2 - Go to "manage form display" of paragraph "file info" and chose "Media Library" and save it.

3 - On content type (for eg. basic page) create a paragraph field and add "file info" paragraph then save it.

3 - Go to "manage form display" of basic page content type and under your field created on step 3 chose "paragraph legacy" with this attributes

[image: print_of_paragraph]

4 - Go to content - add content - basic page - add paragraph

If I set the default date to "-None-", get ajax error.

If I set the default date to "Current date" or "relative date" everything works as expected.

Any thoughs about this?

------EDIT-----

Log error I get from drupal is:

> TypeError: DateTime::createFromFormat(): Argument #2 ($datetime) must
> be of type string, array given in DateTime::createFromFormat()

As I said, if I chose a default value everything works as expected, but drupal should allow if you don't want to have a default value.

Comment: You need an error message. Is there nothing in the recent log messages? If not, enable full error reporting in Drupal and then check the ajax response in the F12-tools of your browser.

Comment: @4uk4 I forgot to add log message on my post, I added on my post

Comment: OK, with the error message you can find this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3052608